# Calculate the shortest route using the fleet telematic API

Tags: routes, here-api, maproute, fleet

I'm using the fleet telematic API to calculate a route for specific "Bus-profiles". So I'm using the param speedFcCat to specify the speed limits for the bus.

The problem is, I can only become the fastest route. I tried to combine driver_cost and vehicle_cost (but these two params are for the cost optimized route) and I found no way to retrieve the "shortest" route.
In the Routing API V7 we could use mode = fastest|shortest|balanced. In Routing API v8 there is only fastest.

Answer (score -1):

In v8 routing you can use "fast" or "short" `routingMode`:

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html

Comment: but only for car mode! I have to use Bus mode and as I wrote in the question I use the fleet telematic Api

Comment: @MarouenMhiri no need to use "!", I am trying to help you. Can you add the routing request to your question?

Comment: what do you mean with the use of "!"? I have to use the telematic API because I need the value of "rest time" and I have to simulate a Bus by using speedFcCat. The question is, is it possible to get the shortest Route with the fleet telematic api?